# Proving the output of a generic function

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

Is there any generic construction to prove the correctness of the output of a function? In other words, is there a general way to produce a witness for the statement $y = f(x)$?

More formally, let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a generic function. Given $f$, is there any general way to build a witness-generating function $p: X \rightarrow W$ and a proposition $V(x, y, w)$ such that, for all $x$, only $V(x, f(x), p(x))$ is true, and verifying $V(x, y, w)$ is faster than computing $f(x)$?

Comment: Don't one way functions disprove this?

Comment: One function that may be a counterexample is the function $f(x)=0$ (for any $x$); yes, it is easy to build a proposition for this $f$; I don't know if you can build one that runs **faster** than computing $f$...

Comment: @poncho that's quite a fair point I guess.

Comment: To clarify, if I'm reading this correctly. You are wondering if there exist a succinct proof and efficient verification algorithm (in time less than evaluating the function) to check if for a public f, x, and y that y=f(x)?

Comment: @Wilson precisely! I know it exists for some functions (e.g., one-way functions can use their output as witnesses), so I am wondering if some more general mechanism exists!

Comment: Consider a generic function f represented by an ensemble of arithmetic circuits, isn't this problem resolved by preprocessing SNARKs? The verifier time complexity is poly-logarithmic in the circuit complexity. There is also a line of literature called verifiable computation that maybe also what you are looking for.

Comment: Let's take poncho's counterexample in context. $f(x)=0$ is a function computable in constant time. Thus, the constant factors in the verification algorithm will outweigh the logarithmic complexity, but for non-trivial functions, this method will beat evaluating the function.